# How to test geo targeting for website?

Tags: php, testing, geolocation, geotargetting

I am implementing GeoTargeting in my website to show different content based on whether traffic is from US or NON US.

I have every thing set up the way it should be. Now I want to test and see if its working for NON US traffic.

How can I do that. I would like to also test features of the website when I am testing for NON US traffic.

Comment: how are you determining their location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two professional solutions:

1. [Geosurf](http://www.geosurf.com/)
2. [GeoEdge](http://www.geoedge.com/)

Both offer a toolbar as plugins for some browsers where you can "simulate" (aka proxy).

Comment: thanks. looks like both of these are good solution. But not interested in paying for this. Any free services out there similar to Geosurf.

Comment: I don't know of any recommendable free alternatives for those two.

Comment: I tested demo of GeoEdge and works like a charm. Its bit slow to load websites sometimes but works great.

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of geolocation database to test against. Here's one: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

From there, it wouldn't be too hard to figure out where users are coming from... though it will never be 100% accurate.

There's also the HTML5 geolocation: http://html5demos.com/geo - but users have to explicitly allow location reporting... and it doesn't work all the time, either, even if they accept.

Comment: i have already done this. Now i want to test is its working or not. Thanks

Comment: I'm confused, why did you ask this question then? :|

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. When I said everything is set up, I meant all the scripts required for geo targeting is done. I used maxmind database as you suggested above. I want to make sure everything is done correctly. So, wanted to test if its working properly. Thanks again.